# Trying to use memcpy to continuously update an array, but failing

Tags: c, arrays, loops, dynamic-arrays

Just some premilinary info, the below code is part of a user space HID driver Im building, so Im going to try my best 
to skip over the sections relating to device conectivity, etc...

I have two main arrays that I focus on which is the buf[] array and the buffer[] array. 
The buffer[] array will be comprised of ranges of hex values that are taken from the buf[] array and appended on to it. 
With the purpose of the buffer[] basically holding a large number of bytes that can then be consumed else where.

But I seem to be running into issues with buffer size growing past 1400, I also feel as though my logic as far as adding 
to the buffer is flawed and not working as I think it is. Is there another way that I should be going about trying to acomplish this end goal?

If this code does not show enough PLEASE let me know and I will make the neccesary edits, Im desperate for the help 
and still very new to C. Thank you!

full code found here if necessary http://pastebin.com/cyawpXCq

```
int int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
unsigned char buf[64];
unsigned char buffer[1400]; //1400 is the max size this should ever be
int i;
size_t buffer_length = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    // in this loop I add elements to the buf[]
    // these elements are sent to the device 
    // which then returns the buf[] with new elements
    // in it. 

    // I then want to push a range of these elements
    // into the buffer which I am attempeting like so
    // I skip the first 7 elements and take the
    // next 16 elements which follow and append those to
    // the buffer[].

    memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, buf + 8, 16);
    printf("\nStored Buffer - \n");
    for (size_t i= 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
    }

    // add another 16 to the length
    buffer_length += 16;

    // loop breaks based on another condition
    break;
}

// This condition comes next and does a similar 
// thing as above

if(true)
{
    // buf[] gets returned to 
    // me containing hex values from a device. I now 
    // want to append these values into the buffer[]
    // and take the 30 elements which come after the 
    // first 7.

    memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, buf + 8, 30);
    printf("\nStored Buffer - \n");
    for (size_t i= 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
    }

    // add another 30 to the length 
    buffer_length += 30;
}

// this loop can can return up to about 200 unique buf[] arrays  
// and again is doing a similar thing where buf[] is filled with device 
// data 
for( int address = 0x0370; address < 0x0370 + 1400 + 1400; address += 28)
{
    // I want to append 28 elements following the 7th element from buf[]
    // to the end of the buffer[] on each iteration

    memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, buf + 8, 28);
    printf("\nStored Buffer - \n");
    for (size_t i= 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
    }

    // add 28 to length each time.
    buffer_length += 28;
    printf("buffer_length = %zu", buffer_length);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second loop alone adds 2800 to `buffer_length`, of course you are going over 1400.

Comment: @Nick how did you figure that out? This is where I'm stuck at, it's is probably blatantly obvious but I'm completely missing it.

Comment: 0x0370 + 1400 + 1400 - 0x0370 = 2800, but the increment is 28, so the loop iterates 100 times.
On each iteration you add 28 to `buffer_length`. 28 * 100 = 2800.

Comment: @Nick thanks for pointing that out! Does the way I'm using memcpy make sense for this type of thing?

Comment: it does, but you should do a boundary check before each one.

Comment: You may also be interested in realloc()

Comment: @Corey I have looked into realloc but can't find a good example of how to use it in a similar fashion as this.

Comment: @Corey if you know of one please share.